# Firstdata pAyment integration

Tags: php, payment-gateway, firstdata

i have downloaded the code from firstdata site and trying to implement,

```
        class SoapClientHMAC extends SoapClient {
        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = NULL) {
    global $context;
    $hmackey = "xxx"; // <-- Insert your HMAC key here
    $keyid = "xxxxxx"; // <-- Insert the Key ID here
    $hashtime = date("c");
    $hashstr = "POST\ntext/xml; charset=utf-8\n" . sha1($request) . "\n" . $hashtime . "\n" . parse_url($location,PHP_URL_PATH);
    $authstr = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1",$hashstr,$hmackey,TRUE));
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.11') == -1) {
        ini_set("user_agent", "PHP-SOAP/" . PHP_VERSION . "\r\nAuthorization: GGE4_API " . $keyid . ":" . $authstr . "\r\nx-gge4-date: " . $hashtime . "\r\nx-gge4-content-sha1: " . sha1($request));
          } 
       else {
        stream_context_set_option($context,array("http" => array("header" => "aut horization: GGE4_API " . $keyid . ":" . $authstr . "\r\nx-gge4-date: " . $hashtime . "\r\nx-gge4-content-sha1: " . sha1($request))));
            }
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
         }

          public function SoapClientHMAC($wsdl, $options = NULL) {
    global $context;
    $context = stream_context_create();
    $options['stream_context'] = $context;
    return parent::SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
     }
       }

      $trxnProperties = array(
             "User_Name"=>"",
       "Secure_AuthResult"=>"",
        "Ecommerce_Flag"=>"",
        "XID"=>"",
        "ExactID"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_ExactID"],                  //Payment Gateway
       "CAVV"=>"",
       "Password"=>"********",                                   //Gateway       Password
        "CAVV_Algorithm"=>"",
        "Transaction_Type"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_Transaction_Type"],//Transaction Code I.E. Purchase="00" Pre-Authorization="01" etc.
      "Reference_No"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Reference_No"],
        "Customer_Ref"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Customer_Ref"],
          "Reference_3"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Reference_3"],
        "Client_IP"=>"",                                      //This value is only used for fraud investigation.
          "Client_Email"=>$_POST["tb_Client_Email"],            //This value is only used for fraud investigation.
  "Language"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_Language"],                //English="en" French="fr"
          "Card_Number"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Card_Number"],           //For Testing, Use Test#s VISA="4111111111111111" MasterCard="5500000000000004" etc.
  "Expiry_Date"=>$_POST["ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Month"] . $_POST["ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Year"],//This value should be in the format MM/YY.
  "CardHoldersName"=>$_POST["tbPOS_CardHoldersName"],
        "Track1"=>"",
          "Track2"=>"",
       "Authorization_Num"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Authorization_Num"],
           "Transaction_Tag"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Transaction_Tag"],
           "DollarAmount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_DollarAmount"],
          "VerificationStr1"=>$_POST["tbPOS_VerificationStr1"],
            "VerificationStr2"=>"",
  "CVD_Presence_Ind"=>"",
  "Secure_AuthRequired"=>"",
  "Currency"=>"",
  "PartialRedemption"=>"",

          // Level 2 fields 
         "ZipCode"=>$_POST["tbPOS_ZipCode"],
          "Tax1Amount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax1Amount"],
         "Tax1Number"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax1Number"],


     "Tax2Amount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax2Amount"],
      "Tax2Number"=>$_POST["tbPOS_Tax2Number"],



     //"SurchargeAmount"=>$_POST["tbPOS_SurchargeAmount"], //Used for debit transactions only
      //"PAN"=>$_POST["tbPOS_PAN"]                          //Used for debit transactions only
      );


    $client = new SoapClientHMAC("https://api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/transaction/v12/wsdl");
    $trxnResult = $client->SendAndCommit($trxnProperties);


    if(@$client->fault){
        // there was a fault, inform
        print "<B>FAULT:  Code: {$client->faultcode} <BR />";
        print "String: {$client->faultstring} </B>";
        $trxnResult["CTR"] = "There was an error while processing. No TRANSACTION DATA IN CTR!";
    }
    //Uncomment the following commented code to display the full results.

    echo "<H3><U>Transaction Properties BEFORE Processing</U></H3>";
    echo "<TABLE border='0'>\n";
    echo " <TR><TD><B>Property</B></TD><TD><B>Value</B></TD></TR>\n";
    foreach($trxnProperties as $key=>$value){
        echo " <TR><TD>$key</TD><TD>:$value</TD></TR>\n";
    }
    echo "</TABLE>\n";

    echo "<H3><U>Transaction Properties AFTER Processing</U></H3>";
    echo "<TABLE border='0'>\n";
    echo " <TR><TD><B>Property</B></TD><TD><B>Value</B></TD></TR>\n";
    foreach($trxnResult as $key=>$value){
        $value = nl2br($value);
        echo " <TR><TD valign='top'>$key</TD><TD>:$value</TD></TR>\n";
    }
    echo "</TABLE>\n";


    // kill object
    unset($client);









<form action="process.php" method="post">
        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="660" align="left" border="0">
            <tr><td>
            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="660" align="left" border="0">
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="5"><b>First Data Global Gateway e4℠ POS</b></font></td>
</tr>

            </table></td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <table cellSpacing="6" cellPadding="0" width="660" align="left" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>Gateway ID</b></font></td>
                    <td><input name="ddlPOS_ExactID" id="ddlPOS_ExactID" style="width:125px;" value=""/>
                    </td>

            <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"> <font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>Dollar</b></font></td>
                    <td><input name="tbPOS_DollarAmount" type="text" value="100" maxlength="8" id="tbPOS_DollarAmount" tabindex="4" style="width:122px;" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>Transaction Type</b></font></td>

                    <td colSpan="3">
                        <select name="ddlPOS_Transaction_Type" id="ddlPOS_Transaction_Type" style="width:452px;">
                            <option value="01">Pre-Auhorization</option>
                            <option value="05">Pre-Authorization Only</option>
                            <option value="02">Pre-Authorization Completion</option>
                            <option value="03">Forced Post</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="00">Purchase</option>
                            <option value="11">Purchase Correction</option>
                            <option value="13">Void</option>
                            <option value="04">Refund</option>
                            <option value="12">Refund Correction</option>
                            <option value="40">Recurring Seed</option>
                            <option value="32">Tagged Pre-Authorization Completion</option>
                            <option value="30">Tagged Purchase</option>
                            <option value="34">Tagged Refund</option>
                            <option value="60">Secure Storage</option>
                        </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>Cardholder</b></font></td>
                    <td colSpan="3"><input name="tbPOS_CardHoldersName" type="text" value="PHP WebService Client" maxlength="50" id="tbPOS_CardHoldersName" tabindex="5" style="width:452px;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B>Card Number</B></FONT></td>
                    <td><input name="tbPOS_Card_Number" type="text" value="4111111111111111" maxlength="16" id="tbPOS_Card_Number" tabindex="9" style="width:150px;" /></td>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B>Expiry Date</B></FONT></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Month" id="ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Month" style="width:61px;">
                            <option value="01">Jan</option>
                            <option value="02">Feb</option>
                            <option value="03">Mar</option>
                            <option value="04">Apr</option>
                            <option value="05">May</option>
                            <option value="06">Jun</option>
                            <option value="07">Jul</option>
                            <option value="08">Aug</option>
                            <option value="09">Sep</option>
                            <option value="10">Oct</option>
                            <option value="11">Nov</option>
                            <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Year" id="ddlPOS_Expiry_Date_Year" style="width:61px;">
                            <option value="12">2012</option>
                            <option value="13">2013</option>
                            <option value="14" selected>2014</option>

                            <option value="15" selected>2015</option>

                            <option value="15" selected>2016</option>
                            <option value="15" selected>2017</option>

                    </select></td>
                    </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>AVS</b></font></td>
                    <td colSpan="3"><input name="tbPOS_VerificationStr1" type="text" maxlength="40" id="tbPOS_VerificationStr1" style="width:452px;" /></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><strong><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Zip Code</font></strong></td>
                    <td colspan="3"><input name="tbPOS_ZipCode" type="text" id="tbPOS_ZipCode" style="width:100px;" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><strong><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tax 1 Amount</font></strong></td>
                    <td><input name="tbPOS_Tax1Amount" type="text" id="tbPOS_Tax1Amount" style="width:100px;" maxlength="10"></td>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><strong><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tax 1 Number</font></strong></td>
                    <td><input name="tbPOS_Tax1Number" type="text" id="tbPOS_Tax1Number" style="width:100px;" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><strong><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tax 2 Amount</font></strong></td>
                    <td><input name="tbPOS_Tax2Amount" type="text" id="tbPOS_Tax2Amount" style="width:100px;" maxlength="10"></td>
                    <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><strong><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Tax 2 Number</font></strong></td>
                    <td ><input name="tbPOS_Tax2Number" type="text" id="tbPOS_Tax2Number" style="width:100px;" maxlength="10"></td>
                </tr>



                    <tr>
                        <td align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>Transaction Tag</b></font></td>
                        <td><input name="tbPOS_Transaction_Tag" type="text" maxlength="9" id="tbPOS_Transaction_Tag" tabindex="11" style="width:122px;" /></td>
                        <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b>Authorization No.</b></font></td>
                        <td><input name="tbPOS_Authorization_Num" type="text" maxlength="12" id="tbPOS_Authorization_Num" tabindex="12" style="width:122px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right"><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B>Reference
                                            No.</B></FONT></B></FONT></B></FONT></B></FONT></td>
                        <td><input name="tbPOS_Reference_No" type="text" maxlength="50" id="tbPOS_Reference_No" tabindex="6" style="width:122px;" /></td>
                        <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B>Reference
                                                                3</B></FONT></B></FONT></b></font></td>
                        <td><input name="tbPOS_Reference_3" type="text" maxlength="30" id="tbPOS_Reference_3" tabindex="8" style="width:122px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B>Customer Ref.</B></FONT></B></FONT></b></font></td>
                        <td><input name="tbPOS_Customer_Ref" type="text" maxlength="50" id="tbPOS_Customer_Ref" tabindex="7" style="width:122px;" /></td>
                        <td style="WIDTH: 163px" align="right"><font face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><b><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B><FONT face="verdana,arial,helvetica" size="2"><B>Language</B></FONT></B></FONT></b></font></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="ddlPOS_Language" id="ddlPOS_Language" style="width:125px;">
                                <option selected="selected" value="en">English</option>
                                <option value="fr">French</option>
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="WIDTH: 158px" align="right"><strong><font size="2" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Client E-mail</font></strong></td>
                        <td colspan="3"><input name="tb_Client_Email" type="text" id="tb_Client_Email" style="width:452px;"></td>
                    </tr>

            <tr>
                        <td align="center" colSpan="4">&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="btnPOS_Submit" value="Process" id="btnPOS_Submit" style="width:335px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </table></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

This code is processing the transaction but how to sent the reciept in mail of the user, i used pay button as well but i need to store the data in database so can not continue with button, if someone have implement database integration using pay button plaese help
OR please help me that how to send the reciept in mail of the user.